# Spring Boot YAML Config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application for which I am not able to change the code. I'd prefer to configure it using YML, however I am hitting this YAML limitation:

> Elements have a value or children, never both.

The config scheme for the application includes multiple instances of:

```
com.company.feature=default
com.company.feature.config=value
```

Is there any way to configure these as YAML, as the following would be invalid:

```
com:
  company:
    feature: default
      config: value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put it all in one hierarchy.  Any property whose key has children and a value must be listed with the value without the heirarchy.

GOOD EXAMPLE:

```
com:
  company:
    feature: 
      config: value
com.company.feature: default
```

BAD EXAMPLE

```
com:
  company:
    feature:
      config: value
com:
  company:
    feature: default
```

If you tried to do previous code then according to YAML, you overwrote `com:company:feature` with `default` instead of `config: value`